# how to random button when activity start

Tags: android

I would like to know on how to randomly the button when activity start.

I have 5 button as bellow code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom|center">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/q1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_btn_q_normal" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/q2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_btn_q_normal" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/q3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_btn_q_normal" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/q4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_btn_q_normal" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/q5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_btn_q_normal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So, how can I random it when activity start.
Let's say I start activity 3 times:

```
1st start activity, button will be list as horizontal like as q1/q2/q3/q4/q5
2st start activity, button will be list as horizontal like as q4/q2/q1/q3/q5
3st start activity, button will be list as horizontal like as q1/q5/q2/q4/q3
```

Like this.

Thanks you

Comment: Your are missing something in your question. What do you want randomly? Random position, random color, random size?

Comment: Hi RvdK, I would like to random button position. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**LinearLayout** is a view group that aligns all children in a single direction, vertically or horizontally. All children of a LinearLayout are **stacked one after the other**.

My guess is you want to display some buttons randomly on a layout. So I suggest you to work whether with RelativeLayout because you can move children easily or to build your Layout directly in the Java implementation (generate a **Random** or use **Collection.shuffle(List**).